How to print a floating-point number in a non-scientific form, but without fixed number of trailing digits?
I have a set of doubles that I want to print. My requirements are:

no scientific notation
Up to 4 digits after a dot, but if there are zeroes, those should be trimmed (including the dot, if possible)

Unfortunately, no formatting library gives a way to achieve precisely that (I think?)
To give an example:
#include <iostream>
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <iomanip>
int main() {
    std::cout << fmt::format("{:.4}\n", 123456789.1);                       //bad: prints 1.235e+08
    std::cout << std::setprecision(4) << 123456789.1 << "\n";               //as above
    std::cout << fmt::format("{:.4f}\n", 123456789.1);                      //bad: prints trailing zeros: 123456789.1000
    printf("%.4f\n", 123456789.1);                                          //as above
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4) << 123456789.1 << "\n"; //as above
}

My current solution is more by hand: printing it as {:.4f} and then manually trimming trailing zeroes. But surely, there must be a more elegant solution?

Your question requires non-scientific form and std::cout << std::setprecision(4) << std::noshowpoint << std::fixed <<  123456789.1 << "\n";  prints 123456789.1000 ... std::noshowpoint doesn't work with std::fixed

The duplicated question answers do the manual string manipulation. I was hoping for a more elegant solution, as the manual transformations tend to include subtle corner-case bugs. But I guess there is no such option; at least not to be found here.

String manipulation or a custom formatting routine probably is the only way because otherwise the requirement breaks every data sanity rule.

Cutting off trailing zeroes removes information about rounding and precision of shown figure. That's why most of libraries since day immemorial wouldn't offer that.
123456789.1000 says that rounding happened at 5th digit after point, 123456789.1 says that rounding happened at 2nd digit if format is set to single digit after point OR, in some cases, it's a precise value. Which usually not the case and still expanded by trailing zeroes, for bureaucratic reasons. It cannot be precise value, because it's actually 123456789.0999999940395355224609375, so latter is somewhat ambigous.

It probably would be possible to find such thing in non-coformist environments,e.g Perl or Python, where developers decided to do everything differently (e.g. negative indexes, numerical formats or modulo operator working differently from any other language). I know one project which they used javascript for formatted output via JSON just for sake of using particular rules, matching what they display in web version XD
